# setState key with dynamic index not working - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to `setState` using index inside `for` loop like the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
  this.setState({
    location_option[i]: resourceData.location_option+i,
    location_option[i]_type: resourceData.location_option+i+_type,
  });
}
```

This is how i'm getting the resource data

```
    var resource_eng = { 
       location_option1: "Headquarters", 
       location_option1_type: "Office"
       ...
    }
```

then i get the resource like the following

```
var resourceDataObj = {}
resourceDataObj.en = resource_en.resource_eng;
resourceDataObj.ar = resource_ar.resource_ar;
var resourceData = new LocalizedStrings(resourceDataObj);
var resourceData = this.child.getResourceData();
```

I want to `setState` and get the state as following

```
this.state.location_option0
this.state.location_option0_type
this.state.location_option1
this.state.location_option1_type
```

and so on...but the build is failing with the following error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: Step6.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (63:23)

  61 |     for (var i = 0; i <= this.state.index; i++) {
  62 |       this.setState({
> 63 |         location_option[i]: resourceData.location_option+i,
```

Comment: As the error message shows, you have an extra comma in line 63: `location_option[i]_type: resourceData.location_option+i+_type`

Comment: @AnaLizaPandac it is not extra comma, i'm setting 2 states inside setState

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax for generating dynamic key is not correct. You can use template string to generate dynamic key for type. I am assuming your resourceData looks something like.

```
const resourceData = {
   location_option1: "somedata",
   location_option1_type: "sometype",
}

for (var i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
      this.setState({
        [`location_option${i}]: resourceData[`location_option${i}`],
        [`location_option${i}_type`]: resourceData[`location_option${i}_type`],
      });
    }
```

Comment: when i try your code it builds successfully but on the console it throws error index_bundle.js:77 ReferenceError: location_option is not defined
    at t.value (index_bundle.js:93)

Comment: updated my answer. I thought key was inside location_option but now i understood it's simple string. Can you try now?

Comment: now, when i do console.log(this.state.location_option1) it says undefined although i have location_option1: "Headquarters", location_option1_type: "Office" in my resource data

Comment: can you tell me how your resourceData looks like?

Comment: var resource_eng = { location_option1: "Headquarters", location_option1_type: "Office"...} then i get the resource like the following var resourceData = this.child.getResourceData(); then resourceData.location_option1

Comment: what do you get if you console this resourceData[`location_option${i}`]

Comment: console.log(resourceData[location_option1]) doesn't work it says index_bundle.js:77 ReferenceError: location_option1 is not defined,  but console.log(resourceData.location_option1) works!!!

Answer (score 0):

its always better to keep an array as state variable and then iterate over it to get the value

```
let location = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
  location[i] = {
    option: resourceData[`location_option${i}`],
    type: resourceData[`location_option${i}_type`]
   };
}
this.setState({ location }); // shorthand for this.setState({ location: location });
```

Now, you can just use `this.state.location` variable anywhere you want.